# Trying to set a property value, but it's nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I declared a protocol in the header file of a Controller that manages a map view.

```
@protocol UCMapViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)pushMapviewRight;

@end
```

I'm declaring the implementation of the protocol in another view controller (.h) and implement it in the .m file

```
// in the UCRootViewController.h
@interface UCRootViewController : UIViewController <UCMapviewDelegate>

// in the UCRootViewController.m
- (void)pushMapviewRight
{
    NSLog(@"push mapview right");
}
```

I'm setting the delegate to a property that points to the rootviewController. This is done in the viewDidLoad() of my MapviewController, with a property `@property (weak, nonatomic) id<UCMapViewDelegate> delegate;`.

```
// in UCRootViewController
self.mapviewController.rootviewController = self;

// in UCMapViewController
self.delegate = (id<UCMapviewDelegate>)self.rootviewController;
```

Calling the delegated method. showMenu() gets executed when a button in the mapviewController gets pressed and it works. but the delegate method does NOT get called.

```
- (void)showMenu
{
    NSLog(@"show menu");
    [self.delegate pushMapviewRight];
}
```

But nothing happens.. what is wrong?! Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: By declaring your intent to conform to the delegate in the .h instead of all of that crazy casting, it'll save a lot of awkwardness.  Don't set delegates in the appDelegate either (that's not what it's for), set them inside the relevant delegate class (in your case UCRootViewController)

Comment: it is not set in the appDelegate.. I set the delegate for my mapviewController (which should be UCRootViewController) in its viewDidLoad

Comment: What do you see if you log the value of `self.rootviewController` where you assign the delegate?

Comment: phillip Mills: see my edit ... the value is nil, but I don't see why it would, because when I set the rootviewController, self is cannot be nil?

Comment: If this isn't from the appDelegate, then what is the property `rootViewController` then? Because UIViewControllers don't have a rootViewController property, only UINavigationControllers do.

Comment: I declared it as a property of ViewControllers that get managed by UCRootViewController. I manage some Controllers, and their rootViewController is an instance of UCRootViewController

Comment: How are you referencing this? self.mapviewController.rootviewController = self; how did you tell the UCRootViewController that its mapviewController pointer points to UCMapViewController?

Comment: Use the same logic one step up the chain and log the value of `self.mapviewController` at the point where you set its `rootviewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. At first I used NSLog to verify that self was not nil (which is pretty obvious
, but still) I'm actually not sure why, but `self.mapviewController.rootviewController = self;` did not "carry over" to the point where I wanted to reference self.rootViewController, although self was not nil at the point where I set it to be the pointer to rootViewController.

I fixed it by creating another `initWithRootViewController:(UCRootViewController*) ctrl`and passed self as an argument when I created the MapViewController.

Can someone explain why the valid reference to self (=rootViewController), was not available in the MapViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `rootViewController` property a strong reference or a weak one?  It should probably be strong.  If there are no weak references to the object, then it will be immediately released, and weak references get nilled out when the objects they point to are released.  You need a strong reference somewhere in your application for objects to hang around.

Comment: it is/was strong. maybe you can take a look at my answer and explain to me?

Comment: Are you sure you're assigning to the `rootViewController` *before* you take that and assign it to the `delegate` property?  Put breakpoints on both and see which gets triggered first.

Comment: Yes I did. but I fixed my problem, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

As @CodaFi said, your codes look messy. Why do you set delegate property value in UCMapViewController? The delegate should be set in its parent when popup or prepare for the segue.

Basically, if your UCMapViewController has knowledge about UCRootViewController implementing a delegate method, why not call its method from riitVuewController directly? No need to set delegate at all.

Here is one example of using storyboard and segue, UCMyViewController is going to push segue to UCMapViewController:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  ...
  [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self.rootViewController];
  ...
}
```

Comment: yes. I deleted the references to the rootViewController, and set the delegate with an initWithDelegate method